# Как сравнить 2 JSONObject

Tags: java, json, lombok

С апи приходит объект, в нем есть org.json.simple.JSONObject. И из базы я достаю данные и преобразовываю то же в JSONObject. Если привести оба объекта к строке и сравнить через equals, то результат будет положительный (true). Я использую `@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"myfield"})` из Ломбока.

Но если я сделаю так:

```
MyJsonObject.equals(MyJsonObject2)
```

я получу отрицательный результат.

Путем эмпирических испытаний выяснил, что если JSON состоит из 2х пар ключь-значение, по метод equals на них работает. Но если сравнивать одинаковые объекты с тремя парами значений, то equals всегда выдает false.

Та же самая ситуация, если я попытаюсь преобразовать к HashMap и сравнить через equals. И тут совсем ни при чем аннотации, которые я вешаю на классы. Как вообще такое может быть, что два абсолютно одинаковых объекта эквивалентны, если в них по 2 пары, и не эквивалентны, если 3? Я что-то не понимаю?

Как сравнивать два объекта JSONObject?

Comment: А там `equals` переопределен? Если нет - то это происходит из-за стандартного `Object` `equals`'а, потому что он сравнивает ссылки а не содержимое, а если да - то все таки объекты у вас не равны.

Comment: @AntonSorokin я использовал эту аннотацию @EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"myfield"}). 
Она работает коррекно, если в JSONObject менее 3 полей. А как переопределить equals вручную?

Comment: Так у вас там еще и Ломбок?

Comment: @AntonSorokin да, еще он. Я готов отказаться от аннотации EqualsAndHashCode и прописать явно функцию equals для одного поля. Но как?

Comment: Ну, в C# для этого есть специальные методы, а Java - не знаю, если честно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/185942/3129992

Comment: @XelaNimed а это тут причем, а точнее - как это поможет?

Comment: @AntonSorokin вопрос был не в перезагрузке метода Equals?

Comment: @XelaNimed в перегрузке, но там он использует объекты из библиотеки, он же не сможет изменить их/т.е. изменить библиотечный код

Comment: @AntonSorokin в таком случае писать свой метод для сравнения. Или это тоже невозможно?

Comment: Возможно, только это не так красиво: `equals(MyJSON1, MyJSON2)` или `MyJSON1.equals(MyJSON2)`, а так же этот метод можно использовать только там, где он написан, а не везде где используется `JSONObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что когда я получаю объект из БД, то одно из значений его ключей, например "IntValue": 1 - считается как Long тип (1 - Long). А когда я принимаю запрос эта же еденица считается Int типом. 
Из-за того что типы разные, хоть и значения одинаковые, объекты не раны.
Вывод: в таких местах надо смотреть на типы.